# open text file on server with javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is use an Javascript file (rcrd.js) to access my file (vis.txt)
on the hosting SERVER I use. Then with the file handle I get (fh):

```
// The script file rcrd.js
var vn, tt, rl, ll, rr, cc, nn, tt, 
vn = Form(vd); // from html form input where action is rcrd.js
// Whatever it takes to get the File Handle (fh) for vis.txt and open it for reading
tt = 1;
while (!fh.AtEndOfStream)

{
rl = fh.ReadLine;
ll = rl.length;
rr = ll-4;
cc = rl.substr(0, 4);
nn = rl.substr(4, rr);
if (nn==vn)
{
tt = 0;
break;
}
}
if (tt==1) // End of File and vn not found
{
cc ++;
wl = cc + vn;
// Whatever it takes to open vis.txt for appending
WriteLine(wl); // or however this is to be done
}
```

I know I need to close files, too; but not sure where in the script.....

continue with accessing another file in the same manner and using some of it's data
 eventually calling another (external) URL (compiled from text file data, above)
 so that the user only sees the new URL once the form is submitted
 AND there is no reliance on javascript being enabled on the user's browser...

I tried (using wscript on my XP based computer)

```
var pid, fso, ForReading, fh, rl, lg, dip, ul, ur;
pid = "here";
ForReading = 1;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fh = fso.OpenTextFile("file://G:\SATAHDD\1B\TopSpoT\TREES\Site\tset.txt",ForReading);
while (!fh.AtEndOfStream)
{
rl = fh.ReadLine();
lg = rl.length() - 4;
dip = rl.substr(0, 4);
if  (dip == pid) {
ul = rl.substr(4, lg);
} 
fh.close();
response.write(ul);
}
fh = fso.OpenTextFile("G:\SATAHDD\1B\TopSpoT\TREES\Site\tset.txt", 8, true);
fh.WriteLine("also"+ul);
fh.close();
```

and got an error message:
line 5 char 1 bad filename or number

Comment: ``\`` is an escape character in a JavaScript string literal…

Comment: What @Quentin is getting at is that when you have paths in strings on Windows, you need to use two backslashes `\\ ` in place of one, since `\ ` is reserved for escaping.